# How to create a table like other table and copy its data

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a table just like from another table and copy it's data. It only creating a table. Can someone help me?

Here's my code

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost:3307";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "female"; //database 

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); //open ng connection 
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
$user = $_POST['username'];
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $user LIKE female";

            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $sql ="INSERT INTO $user SELECT * FROM female";
            }   
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to execute your second query.

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     $sql ="INSERT INTO $user SELECT * FROM female";
     $conn->query($sql);
}
```

And please note that a little bit of indenting can make your code a lot more readable.